Azure Log Analytics credential error on .net Web API but not on Console Application
I'm trying to upload logs to Azure Log Analytics using a Web API with .net framework 4.7.2. I made a test in a console application just to check if it works, following this tutorial:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/logs/tutorial-logs-ingestion-portal
Everything works when I run it from the console application, I can see the logs on azure and everything, but when I copy and paste the same code into a web API endpoint I always get this error:
Azure.Identity.AuthenticationFailedExceptionHResult=0x80131500Message=ClientSecretCredential authentication failed: Retry failed after 4 tries. Retry settings can be adjusted in ClientOptions.Retry or by configuring a custom retry policy in ClientOptions.RetryPolicy.Source=Azure.Identity

I assumed I had the wrong kind of permissions on azure but so far I couldn't figure out whats the problem.
Also I'm using a free trial azure account for this test, that might be relevant here.
Code I'm using:

using Azure.Core;
using Azure.Identity;
using Azure.Monitor.Ingestion;

var endpoint = new Uri("XXXXXXXXXXXXX");
var ruleId = "XXXXXXXXXX";
var streamName = "Custom-SimpleLog_CL";

// Create credential and client
var options = new TokenCredentialOptions
{
   AuthorityHost = AzureAuthorityHosts.AzurePublicCloud
};
var credential = new ClientSecretCredential("XXXXXXXXXXXX", "XXXXXXXXXXX", "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX", options);

LogsIngestionClient client = new LogsIngestionClient(endpoint, credential);


// Use BinaryData to serialize instances of an anonymous type into JSON
BinaryData data = BinaryData.FromObjectAsJson(
     new[] {
     new
     {
        RawData = "Some test JSON",
        TimeGenerated = DateTime.UtcNow.ToString()
     }
     });

//Upload logs
try
{
    var response = client.Upload(ruleId, streamName, RequestContent.Create(data));
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Upload failed with Exception " + ex.Message);
}


Are you getting the error locally?

@Harshitha yes, all those tests are being run on my local machine

So after testing things for quite a bit and in different environments I realised to check the security protocol:
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;

Adding this before the upload call solved the issue.
